# Make text image-like(not selectable AND unrecognized by mouse text cursor) with jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using JQuery Selectable items to emulate buttons, I want to make the text in the selectable both unselectable(so it can't be highlighted) but I would also like to make the text cursor from appearing when moused over as well.

Basically I would like the text to act as an image or other non-interactive element. How can I do this?

Comment: ... { cursor:pointer}

Comment: Strange request! Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @mplungjan , `{cursor: default}` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I tried to post default too but my connection was lost

Comment: @mplungjan if you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it solved. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the cursor over specific elements, you can use the `cursor` CSS

For example

```
.def { cursor:default }
```

Or

```
.ptr { cursor:pointer; cursor:hand}
```

and assign the class to the element in question